# Using RegExp in map function

Tags: regex, mongodb, mapreduce

I'd like to MapReduce data I have in MongoDB.
The data is like this:

```
{
  type: 'DOMcheck',
  category: 'Bad label name',
  url: 'http://s1.app.int/part/module/doc/2'
  ...
}
```

Now i'd like to collect all logs and count uniqs by `/part/module` part of the url.
I create `map` function:

```
function() {
  var  re = new RegExp(/^(http:\/\/[\w\.]*)(\/[\w]*\/[\w]*)/),
       u = [];
  u = this.url.match(re);
  emit(u[2], 1);
}
```

and `reduce` function:

```
function(key, val) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i in val) sum += val[i];
  return sum;
}
```

and call MapReduce: `res = db.logs.mapReduce(m, r, {query: {type:"DOMcheck", category: /bad/i}})`

But I have an error:

```
uncaught exception: map reduce failed: {
"assertion" : "map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: u has no properties nofile_b:3",
"assertionCode" : 9014,
"errmsg" : "db assertion failure",
"ok" : 0
}
```

What's wrong with `map` function here? If i `emit(this.url, 1)` map works just fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your regex isn't matching against the url.  That is why u has no properties.

Comment: It's matches. If you simply call the function with parameter, it returns the 3rd element. And i check regex in mongo console - it's works too.

Comment: Uh! I'm sorry. There is one broken url that doesn't matches pattern... Thanks for idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set invalid record percent to skip desired amount of invalid record not failing job. And you can add counter for invalid record.

Comment: They are not invalid. They have a port in the url. Like this `url: 'http://s1.app.int:4000/part/module/doc/2'`. So i just tune regexp and all is fine now. Thanks for reply.

Comment: How do you go about adding this skip?